# Parse and format var_dump data to become more readable

Tags: performance, beginner, php, object-oriented, regex

I have a class that exposes `var_dump` data in order to get better human readable layout.

I have achieved this with a lot of `preg_replace` and a series of regular expressions that run one after another. They parse the result of the `var_dump` to have a more readable and highlighted output.

I would like them to review and verify it in order to optimize it and reduce the code if possible.

**Check the Update 1**

My code can also be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/arcanisgk/test-code-style).

```
<?php //this PHP code is old. In the repository is the updated code, see update # 1.
class ClassVarsManager
{
    private function GetType($var)
    {
        if (in_array($var, ['null', 'NULL', null], true)) {
            return '(Type of NULL)';
        }
        if (in_array($var, ['TRUE', 'FALSE', 'true', 'false', true, false], true)) {
            return 'boolean';
        }
        if (is_array($var)) {
            return 'array';
        }
        if (is_object($var)) {
            return 'object';
        }
        if ((int) $var == $var && is_numeric($var)) {
            return 'integer';
        }
        if ((float) $var == $var && is_numeric($var)) {
            return 'float';
        }
        if (strpos($var, 'resource') !== false) {
            foreach ($this->GetResourceTypeArray() as $value) {
                if (strpos($var, $value) !== false) {
                    return 'resource (' . $value . ')';
                }
            }
        }
        if (strpos($var, '/') !== false) {
            if (in_array($var, timezone_identifiers_list())) {
                return 'time-zone';
            }
        }
        if (strpos($var, ' ') !== false and strpos($var, ':') !== false) {
            $testdate = explode(' ', $var);
            if ($this->ValidateDate($testdate[0], false) && $this->ValidateDate($testdate[1], false && strpos($testdate[1], ':') !== false)) {
                return 'datetime';
            }
        }
        if ($this->ValidateDate($var, false) and strpos($var, ':') !== false) {
            return 'time';
        }
        if ($this->ValidateDate($var, false) and strlen($var) >= 8) {
            return 'date';
        }
        if (is_string($var)) {
            return 'string(' . strlen($var) . ')';
        }
    }

    private function VarExportFormat($var, $highlight = false)
    {
        ob_start();
        var_dump($var);
        $var_dump = ob_get_clean();
        $var_dump = preg_replace(["/\[\"/", "/\"\]/", "/\]/", "/\[/", "/\)\s*\{(\s*\w*)/", "/(\s*\w*)\}(\s*\w*)/", "/=>\s*(\w)/", "/\[\s*\](,)/", "~^ +~m"], ["'", "'", '', '', ') [$1', '$1],$2', ' => $1', '[]$1', '$0$0'], $var_dump);
        $var_dump = preg_split('~\R~', $var_dump);
        $var_dump = preg_replace_callback(
            '/(\s*=>\s*)(NULL)/',
            function ($m) {
                return $m[1] . $this->GetType(str_replace("'", '', $m[2])) . ": {$m[2]},";
            }, $var_dump
        );
        $var_dump = preg_replace_callback(
            '/(\w+\W\d\W)\s*"([^"]+)"$/',
            function ($m) {
                return $this->GetType(str_replace("'", '', $m[2])) . ": {$m[2]},";
            }, $var_dump
        );
        $var_dump = preg_replace_callback(
            '/\w+\((\D+)\)$/',
            function ($m) {
                return $this->GetType(str_replace("'", '', $m[1])) . ": {$m[1]},";
            }, $var_dump
        );
        $var_dump = preg_replace_callback(
            '/\w+\((\d+)\)$/',
            function ($m) {
                return $this->GetType(str_replace("'", '', $m[1])) . ": {$m[1]},";
            }, $var_dump
        );
        $var_dump = preg_replace_callback(
            '/\w+\((\d*\.\d*)\)$/',
            function ($m) {
                return $this->GetType(str_replace("'", '', $m[1])) . ": {$m[1]},";
            }, $var_dump
        );
        $var_dump = preg_replace_callback(
            '/\w+\(\d+\)(\s*)"([^"]*)"$/',
            function ($m) {
                return $m[1] . $this->GetType(str_replace("'", '', $m[2])) . ': "' . $m[2] . '",';
            }, $var_dump
        );
        $var_dump = implode(PHP_EOL, $var_dump);
        $var_dump = preg_replace("/(NULL)(\r|\n)/", '$1,$2', $var_dump);
        $var_dump = preg_replace("/(\w+\s*\[)$/", '$1]', $var_dump);
        $var_dump = rtrim($var_dump, ',');
        if ($highlight && VERSYSTEM !== 'cli') {
            $textvar = highlight_string('<?php ' . PHP_EOL . '/*****  Output of Data *****/' . PHP_EOL . $var_dump . ';' . PHP_EOL . '/*****  Output of Data *****/' . PHP_EOL . '', true);
            $textvar = preg_replace("/\r|\n|<br>/", "", $textvar);
        }
        return $textvar;
    }

    public function VarExport($Var, $Var2 = null, $Var3 = null, $Var4 = null, $Var5 = null)
    {
        echo PRES;
        echo $this->VarExportFormat($Var, true) . EOL_SYS;
        if (null !== $Var2) {
            echo $this->VarExportFormat($Var2, true) . EOL_SYS;
        }
        if (null !== $Var3) {
            echo $this->VarExportFormat($Var3, true) . EOL_SYS;
        }
        if (null !== $Var4) {
            echo $this->VarExportFormat($Var4, true) . EOL_SYS;
        }
        if (null !== $Var5) {
            echo $this->VarExportFormat($Var5, true) . EOL_SYS;
        }
        echo PREE;
    }

    public function ValidateDate($date)
    {
        if (($timestamp = strtotime($date)) != false) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

********UPDATE 1********

**After the Suggestions and Updates from** [mickmackusa](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/141885/mickmackusa).

[class-vars.php](https://github.com/arcanisgk/test-code-style/blob/master/class/classgen/class-vars.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Unless you have a valuable/deliberate reason to use `and` in your condition statements, I recommend consistently using `&&`.  Condition logic can sometimes fall prey to [unintended "precedence" complications](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php#117390).
2. This whole line is "jacked" (wrong / incorrectly coded):

   ```
   if ($this->ValidateDate($testdate[0], false) && $this->ValidateDate($testdate[1], false && strpos($testdate[1], ':') !== false)) {
   ```

   `ValidateDate()` only accepts one parameter, but you are passing two (in several instances to be honest).  The second time that you call this method in this line, you omitted a `)`, so you are effectively doing this:

   ```
   $this->ValidateDate(
       $testdate[1],
       false && strpos($testdate[1], ':') !== false // <-- this, of course, will always be false
       // ...not that the 2nd parameter is ever respected by the method
   )
   ```

   I *think* you mean to write the following:

   ```
   if (strpos($testdate[1], ':') !== false && $this->ValidateDate($testdate[0]) && $this->ValidateDate($testdate[1])) {
   ```
3. I don't like the body of the `ValidateDate()` method at all.

   - It declares `$timestamp` but never uses it.
   - It does a falsey check on `strtotime()`'s return value which can technically return 0.
   - It uses `if` and `else` to explicitly return `true` and `false` instead of returning the evaluation itself.

   I recommend that you scrap the method entirely and just call `strtotime($string) !== false`.  That said, there are LOADS of strings that `strtotime()` will deem to be a date and/or time expression, so I don't know if this is the right form of validation -- maybe this is a subjective judgement call -- the decision/power is yours.
4. Regarding this line:

   ```
   $var_dump = preg_replace(["/\[\"/", "/\"\]/", "/\]/", "/\[/", "/\)\s*\{(\s*\w*)/", "/(\s*\w*)\}(\s*\w*)/", "/=>\s*(\w)/", "/\[\s*\](,)/", "~^ +~m"], ["'", "'", '', '', ') [$1', '$1],$2', ' => $1', '[]$1', '$0$0'], $var_dump);
   ```

   It is far beyond [the recommended character width](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).  It will make your script easier to read if you can avoid horizontal scrolling.  Write each function parameter on a new line. Better still, write the elements on their own line; not only will this improve readability, it will afford you the space to write inline comments if you wish.  Also, the first two patterns are replaced by `'` so just combine the patterns with a pipe.  Same advice with the 3rd and 4th patterns.  Something like this:

   ```
   $var_dump = preg_replace(
        [
            '/\["|"]/',
            "/]|\[/",
            "/\)\s*{(\s*\w*)/",
            "/(\s*\w*)}(\s*\w*)/",
            "/=>\s*(\w)/",
            "/\[\s*](,)/",
            "~^ +~m"
        ],
        [
            "'",
            '',
            ') [$1',
            '$1],$2',
            ' => $1',
            '[]$1',
            '$0$0'
        ],
        $var_dump
    );
   ```
5. You are writing a battery of `preg_replace_callback()` calls on `$var_dump`.  Generally speaking this looks like a perfect candidate for [`preg_replace_callback_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback-array).
6. I notice that you are making several `str_replace()` calls in callbacks where the match string cannot possibly have a single quote in it.  These needless calls should be removed -- just pass the value to the `GetType()` method.
7. This replacement:

   ```
   preg_replace("/(NULL)(\r|\n)/", '$1,$2', $var_dump);
   ```

   could be written without the captures/references as:

   ```
   preg_replace("/NULL\K(?=\R)/", ',', $var_dump);
   ```
8. Pattern&Replacement: `"/(\w+\s*\[)$/", '$1]'` could be: `"/\w+\s*\[$/", '$0]'`
9. `"/\r|\n|<br>/"` can be simplified to `"/\R|<br>/"`
10. I don't see where constants `PRES`, `PREE`, and `EOL_SYS` are defined.
11. I assume that you have arbitrarily decided to permit a maximum of 5 parameters to be passed into your `VarExport()` method.  You needn't make such a rigid distinction.  You can liberate the method and eliminate the battery of `null !==` checks using the splat operator and some native functions.  Check out this [Demonstration](https://3v4l.org/OMZaM):

    ```
    class ClassVarsManager
    {
        private function VarExportFormat($data) {
            return '*' . $data . '*';
        }

        public function VarExport(...$var) {
            echo PRES , implode(EOL_SYS, array_map([$this, 'VarExportFormat'], $var)) , PREE;
        }
    }

    define('PRES', '<pre>');
    define('PREE', '</pre>');
    define('EOL_SYS', "\n");

    $obj = new ClassVarsManager();
    $obj->VarExport('one', 'two', 'three');
    ```

    Output:

    ```
    <pre>*one*
    *two*
    *three*</pre>
    ```

Finally, I just want to say good work.  I know that you have been toiling at this task for a while now.  This is such a great way to challenge yourself and learn new skills.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110103/discussion-on-answer-by-mickmackusa-parse-and-format-var-dump-data-to-become-mor).